# Why my font are not loading from font-face. Please i have been stucked here for a long time

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Hellow i have stuck and I can't understand why @font face working.
I have a folder named "Fonts" and a folder named "Poppins".
Is there any wrong in this code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf') format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ThinItalic.ttf') format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: ttf fonts only work for certain browsers, you need to include the type of font the browser you are using will support (if the path to the font is correct)

Comment: My browser support ttf